# React jest test Promise inside Async

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the below code but I can't seem to get it working. What am I doing wrong? Seems like the async wrapping the promise is causing the issue. No matter what I try I always get errors

```
export const doLogin = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(true)
    })
  };
};

and the test using jest and enzyme

expect(await doLogin('', '')).resolves.toEqual(true);
```

the error i am getting is

```
    expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

    Matcher error: received value must be a promise

    Received has type:  function
    Received has value: [Function anonymous]
```

Comment: `doLogin` doesn't make much sense to me. Why the `new Promise`? You could just do `async () => true` but the function seems overly contrived and loses context. Also, I think `resolves` matcher already awaits the promise whereas `await` explicitly means you're passing `true` into `expect`, so you'd want `expect(await doLogin()()).toBe(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

`doLogin` is regular function that returns async function. `await` needs to be used outside `expect` call because `resolves` makes an assertion return a promise.

It should be:

```
await expect(doLogin('', '')(dispatchMock, getStateMock)).resolves.toEqual(true);
```

Also `(dispatch, getState) => ...` function doesn't benefit from being `async` because it just returns a promise without using `await` syntax.